# pictures are in the same size in all the phones

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I got some bitmaps in my app (the resource images are in all different drawable folders) - and yet, on my 5.5 inch screen and on my friend 5 inch screen - the bitmaps are in the same size.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try these steps
- Refresh Project Dir from IDE.
- Clean Your Project.
- Built it again (Rerun).

---

If this doesn't help check the bitmaps are in right folders(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) according to size or not.

---

Finally if there is no result of above steps, you should check the dpi of both the mobile phones. This might be a case in which both mobile phone lie in same dpi range, so the bitmaps pulled on screen are of same size.